# How to read until EOF and print the even/odd numbers entered?

Tags: c

I have the below C code which reads user input until end of file (ctrl+d) and stores them in an array. Then, it should print all the odd numbers in a line and then even numbers on another line. For some reason it's not working as expected.

When I enter the following:

```
    1
    2
    4
    16
    32
    64
    128
    256
    512
    1024
    2048
    4096

    the output is: 

    Odd numbers were: 
    Even numbers were: 2 16 64 256 1024 4096

    Expected output: 

    Odd numbers were: 1
    Even numbers were: 2 4 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024 2048 4096
```

Code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h> 


int main(void){
    int array[1000];
    int i,j,k;
    int counter = 0; 

    for(i=0; scanf("%d", &array[i]) != EOF; i++){
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
        counter = counter+1; 
    }

    printf("Odd numbers were: ");

    for(j=0; j<counter; j++){
        if(array[j]%2 != 0){
            printf("%d ", array[j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("Even numbers were: ");

    for(k=0; k<counter ; k++){
        if(array[k]%2 == 0){
            printf("%d ", array[k]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: You know you can get rid of `j` and `k` altogether?

Comment: Did you notice the double scanf()s in the first for loop context or is it only me?

Comment: `for(i=0; i < 1000 && scanf("%d", &array[i]) == 1; i++) { counter = counter+1; }`

Comment: The first one is for the end of file condition in the 'for' loop, unless there is a more effective way of doing it, which there probably is.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY can it not be `for(i=0; scanf("%d", &array[i]) == 1; i++,counter++);` ?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Oh, thanks! That works. Sorry, I didn't know that the scanf("%d", &array[i]) == 1; actually reads input. I thought it just checks for end of file.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Of course, you can do that.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thanks, that is also much more efficient

Comment: @SouravGhosh How can I get rid of j and k?

Comment: Also can put `counter = i;` after for-loop.(Remove `counter++`)

Comment: @novice use `i` everywhere, you're anyway re-assigning it to 0 in every loop beginning. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Oh yes, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There is a easier solution for your problem**

**Hope you like it**

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main()
{

   int num,od = 0, ev = 0;
   int odd[1000],even[1000];

   while(scanf("%d",&num) == 1)
   {
      if(num%2==0)
      {
          even[ev] = num;
          ev++;
      }
      else
      {
          odd[od] = num;
          od++;
      }
   }

   printf("Odds numbers are: ");

   for(int i = 0;i<od;i++)
   {
       printf("%d ",odd[i]);
   }

   printf("\nEven numbers are: ");

   for(int i = 0;i<ev;i++)
   {
        printf("%d ",even[i]);
   }


   return 0;
}
```

**program output matched with expected output**

**Happy Coding**

Comment: An explanation of the cure would improve this answer.

Comment: `while(scanf("%d",&num) != EOF)` is an infinite loop should the user enter non-numeric input.  `while(scanf("%d",&num) == 1)` is better.  Better to compare against what is wanted `1` than compare against one of the not wanted return values `EOF`.

Comment: but , user need to use ctrl+Z for end of input in both approach

Comment: In this answer's approach, entering `"1\n"`, `"2\n"`, `"X\n"`, `"4\n"`, `ctrl+Z`, code will loop forever due to `'X'` not being consumed.  Users sometimes make mistakes.   What should code do?  Oblige the user to its needs or provide constructive feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have accepted a complete different approach, but you example was incorrect because you did a `scanf` at each loop stage, and then another one inside the `for` body, so you made **two** `scanf`'s at each loop pass, which made the second value to kill the first in the array element `i`.  This made you to loose half of the read elements and explains the output you got.  Just dropping the `scanf` inside the loop body would make it work fine, probably.