# C - store even numbers until end-of-input

Tags: c

I am trying to create a C program that reads standard input until it reaches the end-of-input, then store the even numbers to an array and prints it.
I don't know why my program isn't working as intended. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int num = getchar();
    int list[10000];//array to store even nums
    int i = 0;
    while(num != EOF){    
        if(num % 2 == 0){
            list[i] = num;//store even nums
            i++;
        }
        num = getchar();
    }
    for(int j = 0;j < i;j++){
        printf("%d ",list[j]);
    }

    return 0;
}
//example output from terminal

Test 8 (1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34) - failed (Incorrect output)
Your program produced these 1 lines of output:
10 10 50 10 10 10 56 10 10 50 10 52 10 
Last line of output above was not terminated with a newline('\n') character

The correct 1 lines of output for this test were:
2 8 34 

The difference between your output(-) and the correct output(+) is:
- 10 10 50 10 10 10 56 10 10 50 10 52 10 
+ 2 8 34 

The input for this test was:
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
```

Comment: Show us the what `input` you provided & expected output. Note that if you hit `ENTER`  like _2ENTER 4ENTER 6ENTER_, `ENTER` key ascii value is `10(even)` which also gets stored in the array.

Comment: @Achal it was run through an auto test, I've attached the output

Comment: Based on i/p provided, `getchar()` is not the correct one to use as `getchar()` reads one-one char at a time so e.g if i/p is like: `123` it reads as `1` then `2` then `3` separately but expected one was `123` as whole integer. Use `fgets()` as suggested by @Kine in answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780946/how-to-read-until-eof-and-print-the-even-odd-numbers-entered first google result *before* you added your answer.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala thanks for this, i've try googling for a good few hours lol

Comment: You should have extracted a [mcve] first. You would have found that input fails already and the rest is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getchar()` reads only one `char` at a time, you need to use a function that reads a complete input.

`scanf("%d", &num);`

or better yet `fgets` and `strtol`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 10000

int main(void)
{
    int list[N];
    int num, i = 0;
    char buf[32], *ptr;

    while ((i < N) && fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
        if (buf[0] == '\n') {
            break;
        }
        num = (int)strtol(buf, &ptr, 10);
        if (*ptr != '\n') { // not a valid number
            continue;
        }
        if (num % 2 == 0) {
            list[i] = num; //store even nums
            i++;
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        printf("%d ", list[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can i still use  while(num != EOF) after assigning value to num using scanf?

Comment: No, then you can not use EOF, instead use a sentinel, i.e. `while (num != 0)`

Comment: @KeineLust: All input functions have a condition for reaching the end of the input, so there's no need for a sentinel.

Comment: @MOehm, yes, thanks for pointing that, edited with an example using `fgets`

Comment: Hmm, but now your code has an added quit command, but it doesn't terminate on end of input. I think the main loop should be `while (i < N && fgets(...))`. And the program interprets any non-numercal input as 0, which will then be added to the list.

Comment: @MOehm you mean that I don't check if the input value is a valid integer? is a trivial thing using the second parameter of `strtol` (left to the OP as an execrcise)

Comment: No, I mean that your program doesn't break the main loop when the end of the input is found, which is a _requirement from the question_. Instead, you've changed the spec to have the user type `q`, which the OP didn't ask for. As for checking the validity: Yes, it is easy and you and I know it, but the newbie OP doesn't.

Comment: @MOehm, oh, I see, anyway this is a short snippet ilustrating the advantages of `fgets` over `scanf` (more flexible and protected from arithmetic overflow).

Comment: `if (ptr == buf)` is a better check for conversion success than `if (*ptr != '\n')`.

Answer (score 3):

If you only get one line of input you don't have to store all numbers, just print them:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num;
    while (scanf("%d", &num) == 1) {
        if(num % 2 == 0)
            printf("%d ", num);
    }
    putchar('\n');  // from your output it is clear that
                    // a newline at the end is expected.
    return 0;
}
```

If you have to handle multiple lines:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>   
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    size_t capacity = 0;
    int *numbers = NULL;
    size_t count = 0;
    int input;

    while (scanf("%d", &input) == 1) {
        if(input % 2 == 0) {
            if(count == capacity) {
                capacity += 10;
                numbers = realloc(numbers, capacity * sizeof(int));
            }
            numbers[count++] = input;
        }
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        printf("%d ", numbers[i]);
    putchar('\n');

    free(numbers);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like your first example for being concise. It handles multiple lines, by the way, and breaks on any non-numerical input.

Comment: @MOehm Yes, but I take it that ouput should be in a single line after all input.

Comment: @chux Embarrassing :/